# usarsim.launch file Is there any error?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

launch

param name="usarsim/robotType" value="P3AT"

param name="usarsim/hostname" value="localhost"

param name="usarsim/port" value="3000"
param name="usarsim/startPosition" value="Vehicle1"

param name="usarsim/odomSensor" value="InsTest"

node name="RosSim" pkg="usarsim_inf" type="usarsim_node"

launch

***I have intentionally left <>  brackets here. Otherwise lines are not visible in the question.***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85786/usarsim.launch-file-is-there-any-error?/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-01**:
Dear Brian, although I am pretty sure what the answer is, can you edit your question and post the error message you receive, to make the question useful for other people too, please?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-02**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/85311/unable-to-connect-usarsim-enviroment-from-ros/

Hi kr1zz; I have already asked the question giving full error details in the above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let me quote your question:

> I have USARSim running on windows7 on
> a desktop and P3AT is loaded using
> Iridium. In my laptop I have ROS
> installed and through a LAN wire I try
> to connect to both machines. I type
> follow commands in my laptop which are
> given below:

> 1. roscore

> 2. roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch

> [ERROR] [1380608092.814131851]: can't
> open socket to localhost port 3000

Then you are trying to connect to localhost, whereas you should try to connect to the computer running windows 7 and USARSim.

Solution: replace the string *localhost* on the second line with the IP address (or the name) of the computer where USARSim is running

---

Originally posted by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) with karma: 116 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2